# Order By child field in One To One relationship Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a one to one relationship like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Modification {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="modification_id")
    Long id;
    
    @Column(name="second_line", length=1000)
    String firstLine;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tm_satus")
    StatusOrder tmStatus;
    
    // Constructors getters and setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class StatusOrder {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="status")
    int status;
    @Column(name="status_order")
    int order;
    // Constructors getters and setters
}
```

So every `Modification` has a `StatusOrder`.

Now I want to perform a query where I select from `Modification` table ordered by `order` field in `StatusOrder`.

Is there a way to have a method in my repository like:

```java
Page<Modification> findAllOrderByStatusOrder(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these,

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Modiciation m ORDER BY m.tmStatus.order DESC")
Page<Modification> findAllOrderByStatusOrder(Pageable pageable);
```

or (I don't know if this'll work.)

```
Page<Modification> findAllOrderBytmStatus_orderDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: The second one worked for me !